# Postgresql INNER JOIN for same table basic on column true or false

Tags: sql, postgresql

Been working through a query and getting stuff on a few things. Some guidance would be greatly appreciated.
...

| Time | Qty | Maker |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1665897966332 | 20 | TRUE |
| 1665897966332 | 15 | FALSE |

Plan is to try and match the time and join the qty side by side, if qty =true, and if qty=false

| Time | s.qty | b.qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1665897966332 | 20 | 15 |

The query so far looks something like this and have tried a few variations

```
SELECT
  s.time ,
  s.quantity AS s,
  s.maker,
  b.quantity as b
FROM agg s
JOIN agg b on (s.time) = (b.time)
WHERE s.maker ='true' AND b.maker='false'
```

Appreciate any pointers .. Thanks

Comment: within a second but not to the millisecond, this probably adds a complication unless where the field they don't match is just set to null or I might have to average the time to a second?  There might not be a b.qty to match each of the s.time entries

Comment: using select date_trunc('seconds', timestamp) has allowed the ts match to be simplified.